# How to get Next Previous Post link in FishPig wordpress integration

Tags: magento-1.8

I am using [Fishpig Wordpress Integration](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/), I would like to display Next and Previous Post link in Post page. In Wordpress we can use `posts_nav_link()` but its not working in magento.

Please guide me if anyone have some idea

I want next previous link like on this url http://www.maisondelgusto.com/en/stories/el-poaig-olive-oil-can-tell-us-so-much/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

androidjunky,

Use the function `getNextPost()` which give your the `next post Object`.

and `getPreviousPost()` give `previous post object`

```
$PreviousPOSTURl =$CurrenTPostOb->getPreviousPost()->getPermalink()
$getNextPostURl =$CurrenTPostOb->getNextPost()->getPermalink()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Amit, but it gives error `Fatal error: Call to a member function getPermalink() on a non-object in`

Comment: is $CurrenTPostOb->getPreviousPost()->getId() give  post id  please check

Comment: Do you know how to get pagination? in post listing page?

Comment: yes..i know it...

Comment: :) Please tell me buddy, how to place pagination